# Connecting two nodes not on same network

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, network

Is it possible to connect two private ethereum nodes that are connected to different internet service providers? I have tried and successfully connected the nodes over same network and it works.

How to connect two nodes that are not using same network, what IP do I need to replace after enode ?

Answer (score 2):

You would need the public IP for a start. But your main issue may in fact be the port to connect to.

I assume that both your nodes are behind their own NATs. Can you forward a port (say `XX`) from the router to the port `30303` of your nodes? Then when you have the `admin.nodeInfo.enode`, you replace the port `30303` with `XX`, and `[::]` with the public IP address. Then do `admin.addPeer(ENODE)` on the other machine.

Comment: Can you please elaborate, unable to figure how to forward a port from the router. Can you help me with a step by step account of things to be done.

Comment: Step by step depends on your router model, supposing you are at home or in office: http://www.wikihow.com/Set-Up-Port-Forwarding-on-a-Router. Alternatively, you would put your node on a cloud-service computer, which typically let you attach a public IP to the computer itself.